# Documentum how share acl between parent and child of a relation?

Tags: acl, relation, documentum

It is possible to share the same ACL between parent and child of a specific relation?

I defined on D2 client a dynamic ACL on parent object, based on some specific object attributes. I also defined a relation with another document object as child.

Now I'm trying to propagate the ACL value from parent to child object. I've done it by code in the following way:

```
IDfACL acl=sProtocollo.getACL();
idfdocument.setACL(acl);
idfdocument.setACLDomain(acl.getDomain());
```

where `sProtocollo` object is parent and `idfdocument` is child.

It works like a charm, but each time I modify parent object attributes responsible of acl modification, this modification is not propagated to its childs.

Is there an automatic way to let the parent acl be applied to its childs on each property modification?

Answer (score 1):

If your parent objects are of the same object type write `TBO` (Typed Based Object) for your parent type. It is Java code and acts like some sort of trigger for objects of specific type.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it should be a good solution for my problem, but I was wondering if D2-Config, or some other config client, have an option to do it in some automatic way. Eg. In autonaming if some properties change their value, you can change a name on each property modification, I mean something like this.